# How to restrict user login in Laravel if email is not verified

Tags: php, laravel, email-verification

I am using 'jrean' package in Laravel for verifying emails of registered users.
https://packagist.org/packages/jrean/laravel-user-verification

The problem I am facing currently is even if the user is registered how can I restrict his access until the email is not verified. I have followed all the steps given in the package tutorial for implementing registration. But they don't have any steps listed for restricting login access. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can overwrite your login method. In L5.2 and asumming you have a verified field in your users table which is boolean you can do something like:

In your app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php add something like:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    /**
       * Handle a login request to the application.
       *
       * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
       * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
       */
      public function login(Request $request)
      {
        $this->validateLogin($request);
        $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();
        if ($throttles && $lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
          $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
          return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }
        $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);
        if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
          if (Auth::user()->verified == true) { // This is the most important part for you
            return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
          } else {
            Auth::logout();
            return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request, "Some message here");
          }
        }
        if ($throttles && !$lockedOut) {
          $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        }
        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
      }
```

You also need to add the verified field in your User eloquent model in order to use it in your modified login method.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can [create simple middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#defining-middleware) and check if email is verified there. For example, if `verified` is boolean in `users` table, you can do this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return auth()->user() && auth()->user()->verified
        ? $next($request); // Will pass user.
        : redirect('/'); // Will redirect user to the main page if email is not verified.
    }      
}
```

Do not forget to [register middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#registering-middleware) and apply it to route(s) you want to protect.

Comment: But I suppose they already have 2 middlewares in their package?
`$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['getVerification', 'getVerificationError']]);`

Answer (score 3):

Apply verified middleware to the URL and it will prevent visiting the URL until user verifies their email. `Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index')->name('users')->middleware('verified');`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
    public function __construct() {
        $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
        if(!$user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            abort($this->respondUnauthorized(trans('response.email_not_verified')));
        }
    }
```

```
hasVerifiedEmail() Determine if the user has verified their email address.
```

It will check for all routes/methods in your controller

Answer (score 0):

```html
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (\App\Models\User::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first()->email_verified_at != null) {
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return redirect('/login')->with('email_not_verified', 'Email not verified, Please check your email to validate it');
    }
}
```